# How to detect some sibling components whether they existed in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a table structure in a React Component like this:

```
<table>
  {theadConditionA && <thead>head-1</thead>}
  <TbodyComponentA />
  <TbodyComponentB />

  {theadConditionB && <thead>head-2</thead>}
  <TbodyComponentC />
  <TbodyComponentD />
</table>
```

`TbodyComponent` has its internal logic to determine whether it is a specific component or `null`.
And I would like to detect the `TbodyComponent` A and B to decide display head-1 or not.

Currently, I use a specific function to extract the significant judgment logics in the `TbodyComponent` and generate the corresponding `theadCondition`.

But it’s too bulky and not efficient enough.
I would like to find a more efficient and concise method.

Actually, the truly situation is more complex, and there are many combinations of `thead` and `tbody` in this table.
And the inner logics that decide the return value of each `tbody` component are different from the other `tbody` components.
If I try to use props passing to decide whether render `thead` part, then the parent component level's logic seems to be hugely complex.

Comment: pls rename `brother` to `sibling` component to get more relevant help :)

Comment: We may need a bit more context here, but couldn't you, say, just explicitly pass it a prop from the parent since the parent component should know exactly what it's rendering? This is the nice thing about React components is that they don't generally concern themselves with the goings-on of components around them other than that they have a parent that passes them props, and they render children and pass props down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of a little trick to bypass this problem, which is CSS.
In reality, I have to consider the alignment situation of the table content. That's why I use a single table in the first.
My solution is to split a single table into multiple tables and use `:last-child` CSS selector to detect whether the `thead` is the last element of the parent element. After that, I can use the CSS attribute `display` to control `thead`.